# Why this "if" does work no as I expect with regular expression in JS

Tags: process

Could somebody explain to me why in this code:

const textInputs=document.querySelectorAll(selector);
textInputs.forEach(i=>{
i.addEventListener('keypress',(e)=>{
if(e.key.match(/[^0-9]/ig)){
e.preventDefault();
}
});
});

Condition "if" does work not as I expect. I expect the e.preventDefault() work when I enter any digits but it works exactly the opposite. I mean e.preventDefault() work when I enter any other symbol but a digits

Answer (score 0):

In your regex the `^` is a negation meaning the regex matches anything that is not digits. Try

```js
if(e.key.match(/[0-9]/ig)){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. But I thought ^ anchors to the beginning of the line. I almost sure I had read it. Can you tell me where can I find more information about it

Comment: That is correct.. outside of a character set. [^...] matches a negated character set